# how to use bracket notation (or an alternative) while programming with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I'm trying to write a function to calculate toplines (as commonly used in polling data). It needs to include both a "percent" and "valid percent" column.

Here's an example

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
# prepare some data
d <- gss_cat %>%
  mutate(tvhours2 = tvhours,
         tvhours2 = replace(tvhours2, tvhours > 5 , "6-8"),
         tvhours2 = replace(tvhours2, tvhours > 8 , "9+"),
         tvhours2 = fct_explicit_na(tvhours2),
         # make a weight variable
         fakeweight = rnorm(n(), mean = 1, sd = .25))
```

The following function works as far as it goes:

```
make.topline <- function(variable, data, weight){
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  weight <- enquo(weight)

  table <- data %>%
    # calculate denominator
    mutate(total = sum(!!weight)) %>%
    # calculate proportions
    group_by(!!variable) %>%
    summarise(pct = (sum(!!weight)/first(total))*100,
              n = sum(!!weight))

  table
}
```

```
make.topline(variable = tvhours2, data = d, weight = fakeweight)
```

[image: image of topline table without valid percent field]

I'm struggling to implement the valid percent column. Here is the syntax I tried.

```
make.topline2 <- function(variable, data, weight){
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  weight <- enquo(weight)

  table <- data %>%
    # calculate denominator
    mutate(total = sum(!!weight),
           valid.total = sum(!!weight[!!variable != "(Missing)"])) %>%
    # calculate proportions
    group_by(!!variable) %>%
    summarise(pct = (sum(!!weight)/first(total))*100,
              valid.pct = (sum(!!weight)/first(valid.total))*100,
              n = sum(!!weight))

  table
}

make.topline2(variable = tvhours2, data = d, weight = fakeweight)
```

This yields the following error:

```
 Error: Base operators are not defined for quosures.
Do you need to unquote the quosure?

  # Bad:
  myquosure != rhs

  # Good:
  !!myquosure != rhs
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

I know the problem is in this line, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
mutate(valid.total = sum(!!weight[!!variable != "(Missing)"]))
```

Comment: Please can you provide some of  gss_cat  as a test data set (use `dput()`). Have a look at the new `{{` operator in `rlang`.

Comment: I know this might sound odd, but try putting parentheses around the `!!weight`.  Like `valid.total = sum((!!weight)[!!variable != "(Missing)"])`.  I think switching to using `{{` instead of `enquo()` and `!!` will also work.

Comment: Thanks everybody! The parentheses solution works. I'll check out the `{{` option too. @aosmith, if you submit your suggestion as an answer, I'll happily accept it. @Richard-Telford, the gss_cat dataset is part of the forcats package, so it will load with my first line `library(tidyverse)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put parentheses around the `!!weight`.  I think of this as making sure we are using the extract brackets only *after* `weight` is unquoted (so an order of operations thing).

That line would then look like:

`valid.total = sum((!!weight)[!!variable != "(Missing)"])`

Alternatively, you could use the new curly-curly operator (`{{`), which takes the place of the `enquo()`/`!!` combination for relatively simple cases like yours.  Then your function would look something like

```
make.topline <- function(variable, data, weight){

    table <- data %>%
        # calculate denominator
        mutate(total = sum({{ weight }}),
               valid.total = sum({{ weight }}[{{ variable }} != "(Missing)"])) %>%
        # calculate proportions
        group_by({{ variable }}) %>%
        summarise(pct = (sum({{ weight }})/first(total))*100,
                  valid.pct = (sum({{ weight }})/first(valid.total))*100,
                  n = sum({{ weight }}))

    table
}
```

Like the parentheses solution, this runs without error.

```
make.topline(variable = tvhours2, data = d, weight = fakeweight)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  tvhours2    pct valid.pct      n
  <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0          3.16      5.98   679.
2 1         10.9      20.6   2342.
3 2         14.1      26.6   3022.
4 3          9.10     17.2   1957.
5 4          6.67     12.6   1432.
6 5          3.24      6.13   696.
7 6-8        4.02      7.61   864.
8 9+         1.67      3.16   358.
9 (Missing) 47.2      89.3  10140.
```